# How do I store multiple data read from hdf5 files in one array?

Tags: c, hdf5

I'm trying to pre-load a bunch of matrices from HDF5 files and store them in one dynamic array. However, I'm not able to get it to work like I would like it to.
For some reason that I can't figure out, the whole array is overwritten rather than the sub-array. Any ideas how to fix that?

Here is my code:

```
short ***data[line_count];
short** dset_data;

for (int file_index = 0; file_index < line_count; ++file_index){
    dset_data = (short**) malloc(DIM_Y * sizeof(short*));
    dset_data[0] = (short*) malloc(DIM_Y * DIM_X * sizeof(short));
    for (int i=1; i < DIM_Y; i++)
      dset_data[i] = dset_data[0] + i * DIM_X;

    for (int y = 0; y < DIM_Y; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < DIM_X; x++) {
                dset_data[y][x] = 0;
        }
    }
    /* Open an existing file. */
    file_id = H5Fopen(input_files[file_index], H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);

    /* Open an existing dataset. */
    dataset_id = H5Dopen2(file_id, "data/data", H5P_DEFAULT);

    /* Read dataset */
    status = H5Dread(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_SHORT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &dset_data[0][0]);

    /* Store two dimensional array at n-th position in data array */
    data[file_index] = &dset_data;

    /* Close the dataset. */
    status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);

    /* Close the file. */
    status = H5Fclose(file_id);
}
```

Comment: Woow.. A three-star + array. Congratulations, you are the [winner](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a complimentary term.  I'm not willing to spend time working out what an array of triple-pointers is up to — my mind gets fried.  It's almost certainly wrong.  Given the multiple separate memory allocations, you cannot read everything in a single `read` function call.  You might be able to do it with a function that works like POSIX's [`readv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readv.html), but there'd be a lot of setup work to do.

Comment: Hmmm...where does that code actually attempt to use the `data` variable declared as `short ***data[line_count]`?  Are you just trying to scare everyone off before you get started?

Comment: FYI: The H5 functions are documented at [`H5D*()`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html) and [`H5F*()`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5F.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is organizing the datasets read by H5Dread in one array, so I can iterate over them later on. It does not have to be the way I tried to implement it, but that was the only idea I came up with. However, i'm more than happy about any suggestion to do it differently.

Comment: @DanielBecker: Unless there is a reason for including that `short ***data[line_count]` declaration that I've not noticed, get rid of it.  It will scare people off looking at the code.  It scares me witless trying to work out what you might be doing with it!  Then we can do some clean-up on the 3-Star comments.  I recommend including URLs to the documentation as most people won't be familiar with those functions.  You'll need to explain what you mean by 'the whole array is overwritten rather than the sub-array'.  Which whole array?  Which sub-array?  How do you know?

Comment: I'm using `*** data` in this line: `data[file_index] = &dset_data;`. Because of that, I included the declaration.
By overwritten I mean that data[0] will always contain the current dset_data array rather than the one I assigned using the index from the for loop.

Comment: Oh, OK; that's why eyeballs are bad and search is better.  You're record the address of your local variable `data_set` in the the `data[file_index]` entries.  That's not good.  You're going to need to sort out what's going on.  I think you should lose one star from `data`, and assign `data[file_index] = dset_data;`.  And not a lot else needs to change.  You have an array of 2D data sets, not an array of 3D data sets.

Comment: So there was my problem. For some reason I thought I needed three stars to achieve that. But yes, just tested removing one star and it works like charm. And thinking about it, it does make sense, just need an array, not one more dimension to store the data together. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments, minus knee-jerk reactions to triple-star data, into an answer.*</sup>

The declaration of `data`:

```
short ***data[line_count];
```

and the line assigning to it:

```
data[file_index] = &pset_data;
```

are the source of the trouble.  You're storing the address of a local variable — the same local variable — on each iteration.  This is not what you want; you want to store the value that you saved in `pset_data`, not the address where that value is stored.

The quick fix is to lose a star from `data`:

```
short **data[line_count];
```

and then change the assignment to:

```
data[file_index] = pset_data;
```

This should be all that's needed in this code.  The code using `data` will need corresponding adjustments.

If you think about it, `data` is an array of 2D data sets; that only needs the two stars for the data and the subscripts for the array.  It might well be sensible to think in terms of an array of a structure type, where the structure type encapsulates one data set — it would include a pointer to the data itself, and might also include size information, and perhaps it would store the file it came from or other metadata about the data set.  This would avoid the multiple stars issue.  When you have three stars, it is hard to keep track of what's going on.  If you genuinely had N-dimensional data, then you might need N stars in the declaration, but the auxilliary data structures also get to be increasingly rococo.  But aim to avoid triple-star pointers.  As noted in the comments, [Three-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a complimentary epithet.  Occasionally — very occasionally — it is necessary.  It is not often necessary, and should be avoided whenever possible.